# How to limit the width of dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an html table that contains a few dropdownlist.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkorderId)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubmissionDate)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartId)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivityId)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("WorkorderId", (SelectList) ViewBag.Workorders, string.Empty)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubmissionDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield" })</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("PartId", (SelectList) ViewBag.Parts, string.Empty)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("ActivityId", (SelectList) ViewBag.Activities, string.Empty)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

One of the column (The PartId column), has a very long description.  It almost take the whole page.

```
12345 - The very long description for Part
```

I want to limit the width of the dropdown list to as long as the PartNumber (without the Description).  Right now the the width of the dropdown list is equal to the longest of the PartNumer - Description.

Is there a way to only show the PartNumber (12345) when the it's selected, but show the whole thing (Number - Description) when the dropdown is click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the width of dropdownlist to 150px :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("WorkorderId", (SelectList) ViewBag.Workorders, new { @style = "max-width:150px;" }
```

Comment: The catch is that "max-width:150px;" at (least in Chrome) will just truncate the dropdown rather abruptly cutting off anything at the end like the end of the box and losing the dropdown arrow on the right end.

Answer (score 2):

You can add styles in MVC html helpers. Simply use "New" keyword followed by brackets and with in brackets add your style. Like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("WorkorderId", (SelectList) ViewBag.Workorders, new { style = "width:100px;" }
```

Or you can define your CSS class and apply your class in html helpers. You can visit [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/XcX9021112-Inline-CSS-and-Styles-with-Html-Helpers-in-MVC3-Razor.html) to see both the ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the CSS width on the `select` element, it will fix the width of the element to what you want.  However, the options will still be displayed with the full number and description.

```
select {
    width:10em;
}
```